# How to pass Model property from ActionLink to Post method (with asp.net core)?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I've been recreating my project in asp.net core mvc from asp.net mvc.

When I used to delete a Tag object, I would send `Tag.Name`  via the index page's ActionLink to the Delete Post method.

```
@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.TagId, name = item.Name })
```

Then in the controller, on delete (Post), I would access `Name` like so:

```
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Delete(int id, string name)
{
}
```

Though in asp.net core `name` is returned back as `null` in the Post method (though is correctly returned in the Get method).

I can retrieve `name` via `<input asp-for="Name" type="hidden" />` within the Delete's form Post, but I was wondering why I can't retrieve it like I could with asp.net?

**For reference here are the views**

- asp.net

```
<dl class="dl-horizontal">
    <dt>
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </dt>

    <dd>
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
    </dd>

</dl>

@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

    <div class="form-actions no-color">
        <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-default" /> |
        @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
    </div>
}
```

- asp.net core

```
<dl class="row">
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
    </dd>
</dl>

<form asp-action="Delete">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" /> |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</form>
```

Thank you

Comment: You misunderstand how HTTP and HTML work together. `ActionLink` renders an `<a>` element **which can only make `GET` requests**. To make a `POST` request you need a `<form method="post">` element. Can you still submit a form with a link-like appearance by using `<button type="submit" form="formIdGoesHere">Click me</button>`, but you'll need to render that directly and not with `ActionLink`.

Comment: @Dai I understand. Nevertheless, how is the asp.net mvc version able to return the Tag's Name in the Delete `POST` method by declaring it in the ActionLink? When I remove it from the ActionLink it is `Null` in the Delete `POST` method.

Comment: Post requests may bind query parameters. But your .net core form action probably doesn't have any.

Comment: Have you tried [FromQuery] in your parameters ?
public IActionResult Delete([FromQuery] name, [FromQuery] id ......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From my understanding, you can't send a Model property from an ActionLink to a POST method.

e.g ActionLink on the Index page that directs to the Delete page.

`@Html.ActionLink("Delete", "Delete", new { id = item.TagId, name = item.Name })`

You can only pass to a GET method.

With asp.net, apparently the Model property (sent through the ActionLink to the Delete page) was automatically bound as a query parameter, meaning it could be accessible in the POST method.

To do the same with asp.net core, I believe I can just add the Model property as a query parameter in the Form when Posted, like so:

`<form asp-action="Delete" asp-route-name="@Model.Name"> </form>`

This produces the html:

`<form action="/Tag/Delete/9?name=Orange" method="post"> </form>`

Which is then accessible in the POST method

`public ActionResult Delete(int id, string name) {  }`

@Brando Zhang I was having trouble using your method, but I think the result is the same.

Answer (score 0):

As Jeremy Lakeman says, we could pass the parameter as query string to post method, but you should set it in the form tag's action method.

I suggest you could try to modify the asp.net core codes to set the action and method attribute value according to the model name and id.

More details, you could refer to below codes:

```
<dl class="row">
    <dt class="col-sm-2">
        @Html.DisplayNameFor(model => model.Name)
    </dt>
    <dd class="col-sm-10">
        @Html.DisplayFor(model => model.Name)
    </dd>
</dl>
@*Modify the action url to your controller/action*@
<form action="home/delete?name=@Model.Name&id=@Model.Id" method="post">
    <input type="submit" value="Delete" class="btn btn-danger" /> |
    <a asp-action="Index">Back to List</a>
</form>
```

Result:

[image]